# Static class instance inside class

Tags: java, static

I am having a difficult time understanding the way static classes are using in the following scenario.

Let’s say I declare a class as follows:

```
public class TestLibrary {

    private static final TestLibrary library = new TestLibrary();
    private ErrorHandler errorHandler = null;

    public static TestLibrary getLibrary() {
        return library;
    }
    public ErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
        return errorHandler;
    }

    public int run(String[] args) {
        this.initialize(args);
    }

    private void initialize(String[] data) {
        library.errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
    }   
}
```

I now change the class slightly to

```
private void initialize(String[] data) {
    errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
}
```

I declare errorHandler in other classes as follows:

```
private ErrorHandler errorHandler = TestLibrary.getLibrary().getErrorHandler();
```

My code ultimately still functions the same when I use the instance of `errorHandler` in other classes, but I don’t understand why.

Question 1: Shouldn’t the 2nd case create a `new ErrorHandler` that is part of the object `TestLibrary.errorHandler` rather than `library.errorHandler`?

Question 2: Am I doing something wrong?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I get the feeling you want to make `TestLibrary` a singleton and don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: With `library.errorHandler = new ErrorHandler()` you'll always be changing the object referenced by `library`'s `errorHandler`. With `errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();`, you'll be changing `this` object's `errorHandler`.

Comment: @jan Sotirios is correct.  No imports in ErrorHandler.

Comment: You are presenting a class which has a getter on a instance of the same class. Why not just use the constructor?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis So, this confirms my suspicions.  It is changing a different objects `ErrorHandler`.  Thank you.

Comment: The thing is, if you're only every using the `TestLibrary` instance referenced by the `static library` field, then it comes out to the same. You just have redundant references since `this == library` in that first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a static method `getLibrary()` that returns the same instance for all callers. That's called a **Singleton** - although there's better ways to code them.

Then again your supposed Singleton (TestLibrary) exhibits methods that when called **change internal state** - most important, the `ErrorHandler`.

This will cause strange behaviour, especially in multithreaded systems.

Code like this:

```
TestLibrary.getLibrary().run("".split(""));
ErrorHandler eh = TestLibrary.getErrorHandler();
assertEquals(eh, TestLibrary.getErrorHandler());
```

might fail. Because *someone* (meaning: some other thread) might have just happend to call init() between lines 2 and 3, causing ErrorHandler to be set to just another value.

If you **need** to initialize your TestLibrary before use, you should do it *once, and once only* - so you're better of putting this into the constructor of TestLibrary.

If you need TestLibraries that are **intialized different** throughout your code, you should remove the Singleton pattern and stick to plain

```
  TestLibrary tl = new TestLibrary();
  tl.run("".split(""));
```

Read more about Singleton in [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: The speculation is many threads will be using, but each instance of `TestLibrary` will be initialized with different parameters.  Inside the "library" many objects refer back to the same instance of `errorHandler`.  Thank you.